# Software recommendation for a HTML Wordpress Table Generator?

Tags: software-recommendation, wordpress, html

I am looking for a [HTML Table Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables) that runs offline on Ubuntu Linux.

It should provide a visual interface to create Wordpress-compatible tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just go to [the website you linked](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables), do "Save page as" (under the file menu in firefox), and then open the saved copy and use it offline as needed.

Another way would be to select File > Work offline (in firefox, chrome is similar), and then you can load websites you've previously visited while offline.

I tested it, and it seems to mostly work when used offline in this way.

Comment: Thanks! I use Chrome but can't [find the Work offline option](http://i.imgur.com/gYKASl1.png).

Comment: @orschiro In chrome, go to `chrome://flags`, and find the "offline cache mode" entry, and turn it on. Then you'll be able to see pages offline which you previously visited.

Comment: [These](http://i.imgur.com/vS03yhb.png) are the chrome:flags. Maybe you want to add them to your answer. :)

Comment: This solution is just fantastic! I created [this tutorial](https://orzanna.de/2016/06/05/wordpress-com-html-offline-table-editor/) to guide new users. :-)